# No output if any params used in Positioned - Rare case #120698

Tags: flutter, dart

### Steps to Reproduce

Create a Flutter project.
Make a list of containers.
run `.map()` function on it which returns `Positioned()` widget.
Use a list of these positioned widgets inside a `Stack`.

If you use paraments like `top`, `left` etc., no output will be given.
If these are ignored, it works like a charm.

1. Execute `flutter run` on the code sample

**Expected results:**
After removing `top` parameter. Even just using `top: 25` gives no output.
[image]

**Actual results:**
[image]

Code sample

```dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class StackedList extends StatefulWidget {
  const StackedList({
    required this.children,
    this.activeItemCount = 3,
    super.key,
  });

  //List containing all the widgets to be showed as part of stacked UI
  final List<Widget> children;

  //number of items shown
  final int activeItemCount;

  @override
  State<StackedList> createState() => _StackedListState();
}

class _StackedListState extends State<StackedList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Stack(
          children:
              widget.children.map((element) {
        final index = widget.children.indexOf(element);
        return Positioned(
          top: 200 + (index * 10),
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: 1 - (index / 20),
            child: element,
          ),
        );
      }).toList()
          ),
    ));
  }
}
```

```dart
final childrens = <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 75,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 75,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 75,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 75,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                color: Colors.brown,
              ),
            )
          ],
```

Logs
No error logs

```
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0) with
ExtractAarTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0) with AarTransform    
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0) with JetifyTransform 
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0) with
ExtractAarTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0) with AarTransform    
[        ] Transforming savedstate-1.0.0.aar (androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0) with JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming savedstate-1.0.0.aar (androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
[        ] Transforming savedstate-1.0.0.aar (androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0) with AarTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0) with
JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0) with
ExtractAarTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0) with AarTransform  
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0) with     
JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0) with     
ExtractAarTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0) with
AarTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0) with JetifyTransform   
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0) with
ExtractJniTransform
[        ] Transforming tracing-1.0.0.aar (androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0) with JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming tracing-1.0.0.aar (androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform
[        ] Transforming tracing-1.0.0.aar (androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0) with AarTransform
[        ] Transforming core-runtime-2.0.0.aar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0) with JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming core-runtime-2.0.0.aar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0) with ExtractAarTransform       
[        ] Transforming core-runtime-2.0.0.aar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0) with AarTransform
[        ] Transforming core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0) with JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0) with ExtractJniTransform
[        ] Transforming versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) with   
JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) with   
ExtractAarTransform
[        ] Transforming versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) with   
AarTransform
[        ] Transforming collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) with JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) with ExtractJniTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) with
JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) with
ExtractAarTransform
[        ] Transforming lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) with AarTransform[        ] Transforming annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0) with JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming annotation-1.2.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0) with ExtractJniTransform
[        ] Transforming kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10) with JetifyTransform     
[        ] Transforming kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10) with ExtractJniTransform 
[        ] Transforming annotation-experimental-1.1.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0) with    
JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming annotation-experimental-1.1.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0) with    
ExtractAarTransform
[        ] Transforming annotation-experimental-1.1.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0) with    
AarTransform
[        ] Transforming kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.7.10) with       
JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.7.10) with       
ExtractJniTransform
[        ] Transforming annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) with JetifyTransform
[        ] Transforming annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) with ExtractJniTransform
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Skipping task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs (Thread[Execution worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.007 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) started.      
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed.    
Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols (Thread[Execution worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
[        ] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Skipping task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols (Thread[Execution worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:validateSigningDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) started.        
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:validateSigningDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 
0.0 secs.
[        ] :app:validateSigningDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) started.
[        ] > Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:validateSigningDebug' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Skipping task ':app:validateSigningDebug' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :app:validateSigningDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:writeDebugAppMetadata (Thread[Execution worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.       
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:writeDebugAppMetadata (Thread[Execution worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took0.0 secs.
[        ] :app:writeDebugAppMetadata (Thread[Execution worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
[        ] > Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:writeDebugAppMetadata' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Skipping task ':app:writeDebugAppMetadata' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main])      
started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main])      
completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :app:writeDebugAppMetadata (Thread[Execution worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
[        ] :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) started.
[        ] > Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Skipping task ':app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.[        ] > Task :app:compressDebugAssets
[        ] Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:compressDebugAssets' to ensure correctness due tothe following reasons:
[        ]   - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Code
Projects\amazon_echo_page\build\app\intermediates\assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets'. Reason: Task
':app:compressDebugAssets' uses this output of task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug' without declaring an explicit or    
implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are
executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more 
details about this problem.
[        ] Invalidating VFS because task ':app:compressDebugAssets' failed validation
[        ] Not watching anything anymore
[        ] Watching 0 directory hierarchies to track changes
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:compressDebugAssets' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Task ':app:compressDebugAssets' is not up-to-date because:
[        ]   Incremental execution has been disabled to ensure correctness. Please consult deprecation warnings for   
more details.
[        ] The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.
[        ] :app:compressDebugAssets (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.681 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:packageDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) started.
[  +23 ms] Resolve mutations for :app:packageDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0
secs.
[        ] :app:packageDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.
[        ] > Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:packageDebug' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Skipping task ':app:packageDebug' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :app:packageDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.007 secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main])    
started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main])    
completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.
[        ] producer locations for task group 0 (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) started.
[        ] producer locations for task group 0 (Thread[Execution worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
[        ] > Task :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Skipping task ':app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect' as it is up-to-date.
[        ] :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001    
secs.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.
[        ] Resolve mutations for :app:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0    
secs.
[        ] :app:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.
[  +25 ms] > Task :app:assembleDebug
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:assembleDebug' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Task ':app:assembleDebug' is not up-to-date because:
[        ]   Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
[        ] :app:assembleDebug (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.104 secs.
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[        ] You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come    
from your own scripts or plugins.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure       
correctness.
[        ] Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
[        ] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
[        ] 36 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 30 up-to-date
[        ] Watched directory hierarchies: []
[ +529 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 6.5s)
[   +2 ms] Calculate SHA1: LocalDirectory: 'C:\Code
Projects\amazon_echo_page\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk'/app-debug.apk
[ +597 ms] √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
[   +2 ms] executing: C:\src\Android\SDK\build-tools\33.0.1\aapt dump xmltree C:\Code
Projects\amazon_echo_page\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[  +24 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\src\Android\SDK\build-tools\33.0.1\aapt dump xmltree C:\Code
Projects\amazon_echo_page\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x21
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="13" (Raw: "13")
               A: package="com.example.amazon_echo_page" (Raw: "com.example.amazon_echo_page")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x21
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xd
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x21
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")       
               E: application (line=17)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="amazon_echo_page" (Raw: "amazon_echo_page")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.app.Application" (Raw: "android.app.Application")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw:
                 "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=23)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.amazon_echo_page.MainActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.example.amazon_echo_page.MainActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=38)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw:
                     "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: intent-filter (line=42)
                     E: action (line=43)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")   
                     E: category (line=45)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=52)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: uses-library (line=56)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.extensions" (Raw: "androidx.window.extensions")       
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: uses-library (line=59)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.sidecar" (Raw: "androidx.window.sidecar")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
[   +6 ms] Stopping app 'app-debug.apk' on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
[        ] executing: C:\src\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop
com.example.amazon_echo_page
[  +65 ms] executing: C:\src\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages
com.example.amazon_echo_page
[  +97 ms] package:com.example.amazon_echo_page
[   +1 ms] executing: C:\src\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell cat
/data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.amazon_echo_page.sha1
[  +47 ms] 3a2dbb94e641ceb1c011256a71b600fb6d6342f3
[   +1 ms] Latest build already installed.
[        ] executing: C:\src\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +51 ms] --------- beginning of main
           02-14 21:13:59.045 D/CarrierSvcBindHelper(  921): No carrier app for: 0
[   +4 ms] executing: C:\src\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a
android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez     
enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true
com.example.amazon_echo_page/com.example.amazon_echo_page.MainActivity
[  +70 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x20000000
cmp=com.example.amazon_echo_page/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +1 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
[ +559 ms] Observatory URL on device: http://127.0.0.1:36213/YB2WX5_tTgw=/
[   +1 ms] executing: C:\src\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:0 tcp:36213
[  +40 ms] 60200
[        ] Forwarded host port 60200 to device port 36213 for Observatory
[   +4 ms] Caching compiled dill
[  +31 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:60200/YB2WX5_tTgw=/
[ +262 ms] Launching a Dart Developer Service (DDS) instance at http://127.0.0.1:0, connecting to VM service at
http://127.0.0.1:60200/YB2WX5_tTgw=/.
[ +171 ms] DDS is listening at http://127.0.0.1:60203/WwK9SPk9WF0=/.
[  +53 ms] Successfully connected to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:60200/YB2WX5_tTgw=/
[  +71 ms] DevFS: Creating new filesystem on the device (null)
[  +31 ms] DevFS: Created new filesystem on the device
(file:///data/user/0/com.example.amazon_echo_page/code_cache/amazon_echo_pageNQVHSV/amazon_echo_page/)
[   +3 ms] Updating assets
[ +107 ms] Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. for more
information see #56466.
[   +5 ms] Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
[   +3 ms] Compiling dart to kernel with 0 updated files
[        ] Processing bundle.
[   +1 ms] <- recompile package:amazon_echo_page/main.dart 06fa5efe-3a35-4146-8cc0-5480b01cce6b
[        ] <- 06fa5efe-3a35-4146-8cc0-5480b01cce6b
[   +2 ms] Bundle processing done.
[  +87 ms] Updating files.
[        ] DevFS: Sync finished
[   +2 ms] Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64... (completed in 97ms)
[   +1 ms] Synced 0.0MB.
[   +4 ms] <- accept
[   +8 ms] Connected to _flutterView/0x72f67ca58530.
[   +2 ms] Flutter run key commands.
[   +1 ms] r Hot reload. 
[   +4 ms] R Hot restart.
[   +1 ms] h List all available interactive commands.
[   +1 ms] d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
[        ] c Clear the screen
[        ] q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
[        ]  Running with sound null safety 
[        ] An Observatory debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:60203/WwK9SPk9WF0=/
[ +582 ms] The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at:
                    http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:60203/WwK9SPk9WF0=/
```

```
No issues found! (ran in 1.5s)
```

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2546], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.7.0 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b06b8b2710 (3 weeks ago), 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800
    • Engine revision b24591ed32
    • Dart version 2.19.0
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\src\Android\SDK
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 17.4.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 version 17.4.33103.184
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2546]     
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.120
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 109.0.1518.70

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: its fixed by providing other values, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Align widget for this case, else provide width or `left` and `right` value.

```dart
final index = widget.children.indexOf(element);
return Positioned(
  top: 200 + (index * 10),
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  child: Transform.scale(
    scale: 1,
    child: element,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you sm. Idk why it worked but it did... How did you come up with this ans? I'd love to learn from you.

Comment: `left` and `right` is helping understand the size it should take, if you use Align widget, you wont need it. You can find more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)